# Why did my center works so weird

Tags: verbatim, center

I wanna include some code in my text so I use center+BVerbatim environment, but it shifts my code in a weird way.

Here's my code.

```
%%% 一个文档
% 导言：文件格式设置
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
% 该文档为中文文档，故用ctexart，英文文档则可用article
% 选项中的UTF8可有可无，因为这是默认编码
% \documentclass{article}

% 这些包里有一些数学公式
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{commath}

% verbatim居中
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

% 图表
\usepackage{graphicx}

% 这个包提供浮动体排版的方法
\usepackage{float}

% 这个包提供引用高亮与超链接
\usepackage{hyperref}

% 这个包可以打化学方程式
\usepackage{chemformula}

\title{我的第一个 \LaTeX{} 文档}
\author{作者}
\date{2023年5月30日}

% 正文
\begin{document}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\section{自定义命令与自定义环境}
利用\textbackslash newcommand命令可以定义自己需要的命令。
自己定义的命令与内置命令一样，需要以\textbackslash 开头。
而定义的参数则用井号开头。其基本格式如下

\begin{center}
    \begin{BVerbatim}
        \newcommand{命令}{命令含义}
        \newcommand{命令}[参数个数]{命令 #参数编号 的含义}
    \end{BVerbatim}
\end{center}

例如：

\begin{center}
    \begin{BVerbatim}
        \newcommand{\Rho}{\mathrm{P}}
        \newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
    \end{BVerbatim}
\end{center}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

How it works is like
[image]

The left of the page clearly has more blank compare to the right.

Comment: Give the complete code that can be compiled directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the blank space characters before `\newcommand`s since in verbatim environment they will not be ignored:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{BVerbatim}
\newcommand{命令}{命令含义}
\newcommand{命令}[参数个数]{命令 #参数编号 的含义}
    \end{BVerbatim}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my... It works. thx

Comment: @Toby Don't forget to accept this answer :)